# Unable to add free space to root partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I had a problem with the system not booting on a dual-boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu) machine, which seems to stem from depleting all available space for the OS. I tried to follow a guide on YouTube on freeing some space from the D drive on windows, and then converting it to 'ext4' format to increase my root partition.

But, after reaching this last step, I am not able to increase the space of the root partition. I do not know why exactly, as this problem is at the limits of my technical abilities. I looked through questions here and on the internet, and I didn't find this particular problem.

One thing I noticed is that guides which talk about dual-boot systems talk about primary and secondary partitions, but I have no idea what that means.

The youtube guide: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bScShRHX3Yg'

Screenshot of partitions

[image]

I want to add sda9 to sda8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

**Note**: *"I want to add sda9 to sda8"* won't give enough room to Ubuntu.

---

- boot to Windows
- copy/move files from /dev/sda6 (D:?) to /dev/sda5 (C:?)
- delete the /dev/sda6 (D:?) partition using Window's `Disk Management` app

---

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- if /dev/sda9 is truly empty, **delete** the /dev/sda9 partition
- **move** the /dev/sda8 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda8 partition all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did work. I was able to resize it after i deleted 'sda9' (but I wasn't able to move it still). It did show an error when resizing saying that the system file did not extend to the new partition (can't recall exact text). I followed the instruction on that (Right Click -> Check), which solved the problem. I didn't need to use any more space other than sda9. On the swapeon/off thing, I'll have to read on what that means, but I didn't see it in the menu actually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Delete sda9 (rightclick on the partition and choose delete) ---> you will end up with free space --->
Move sda8 to the left, so the free space will be to the right side of sda8 (this may take a wile, because the partition is full) If you can't do this, it is because the partition is too full with data. Cut and paste some files to another partition (for now, you can move it back later). --->
When sda8 has the free space to the right, rightclick and enlarge the partition. 
 IMPORTANT: make backup before you begin.

Comment: Indeed this one of the problems; that I cannot move the root partition around. Per your answer, this means I need to empty it a little bit, but I cannot logon into the system. It does not boot. I read I could do it through the root option in Recover Mode, which I tried, but couldn't do it as it became too complicated for me. If you have any tip how I could free up some space in sda8, I would appreciate it. Otherwise, I will have to try doing it in Recovery mode again.

Comment: Boot your system with the USB-device you used to install Ubuntu. Than you have acces to sda8 ( ext4, therefore Windows cannot see it ) and can move files around. There is also software (for Windows) that can read/write to EXT4 partitions (I never got it to work though). You cannot repartition your ssd when you are booting from it (as it is mounted then).

Comment: re: *"There is also software (for Windows) that can read/write to EXT4 partitions"*... no no no. These drivers that claim to be able to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions will **corrupt** those partitions.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you, good to know. So never use those.

Comment: @JoepieEs Thank you for your help. Your solution is basically similar to -hyennema, which ended up working.